# Append string to last foreach item

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, jwplayer

I am trying to create a foreach which will cycle through a given list of YouTube videos in order to populate a JW Player playlist. The structure of JW Player's syntax allows for the inclusion of multiple videos to build a playlist, however I need to break into the foreach when it reaches the final item in order to close the playlist config.

When not being dynamically generated, the JW Player syntax looks so:

```
<div id='player_1465'></div>
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                  jwplayer("player_1465").setup({
                    height: 360,
                    listbar: {
                        position: 'right',
                        size: 320
                    },
                    width: 960,
                    playlist: [{
                        sources: [
                            { file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DeumyOzKqgI" }
                        ],
                        title: "Skyfall Lyric Video"
                    },{
                        sources: [
                            { file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=diP-o_JxysA" }
                        ],
                        title: "Star Trek Into Darkness Announcement Trailer"
                    }]
                });
                </script>
```

As you can see, each 'source' in the playlist is closed with '},{', with the last one ending with '}]'. I need the foreach to know when it has loaded the final video from the given array and close the playlist section with '}]'.

I have got so far with the dynamically generated code:

```
$clips = $tmdb->getMovieTrailers($tmdb_id);

<div id='player_1465'></div>
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                  jwplayer("player_1465").setup({
                    height: 360,
                    listbar: {
                        position: 'right',
                        size: 320
                    },
                    width: 960,
                    playlist: [{
                        <?php
                            foreach($clips['youtube'] as $yt){
                                echo 'sources: [
                                            { file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $yt['source'] . '" }
                                        ],
                                        title: "' . $yt['name'] . '"
                                        }]'
                            }
                        ?>
                    }]
                });
                </script>
```

Any help given will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using json_encode for this.

```
<?php
$clips = $tmdb->getMovieTrailers($tmdb_id);
$playlist = array();
foreach($clips['youtube'] as $yt) {
    $playlist[] = array(
                        'sources' => array(array('file' => 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $yt['source'])),
                        'title' => $yt['name']
                  );
}
?>

<div id='player_1465'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer("player_1465").setup({
        height: 360,
        listbar: {
            position: 'right',
            size: 320
        },
         width: 960,
         playlist: <?=json_encode($playlist)?>
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get this to work? I've tried to copy and paste the code exactly as it is above, but it blanks out the player completely.

Comment: does the json_encode actually output when you view the html source? perhaps short tags aren't enabled and you need
    <?php echo json_encode($playlist);?>

Comment: That's perfect, I used the full tag and it's found it straight away. Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Get the number of elements in the array with count();
Now you can check in every foreach-loop if it is the last one and can add your bracket!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
    $c = 0;
    foreach($clips['youtube'] as $yt){
        echo 'sources: [
        { file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $yt['source'] . '" }
        ],
        title: "' . $yt['name'] . '"';
        if($c = count($clips['youtube'])){
            echo '}]';
        } else {
            echo '},{';
        }
        $c++;
    }
?>
```